# random.shuffle very slow in Python 3 with list

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, shuffle

I am using python-3.x, and I am trying to generate a list of indexes numbers and shuffle them to use them later to select random values from a sample where this sample will have two variables sample size and dimension number, however here how I generate a list of indexes and them I shuffle them:

```
dimension = 5
sample_size = 100

generate_indexes = itertools.combinations(range(sample_size),dimension)
all_indexes = list(generate_indexes)

# here I do the shuffle
random.shuffle(all_indexes)
```

the problem when I increased the dimension number it will take a long time to give the result even if the dimension number is 5 it takes very long or it will not proceed.

Is there any way to make it fast?

because I have a multidimensional sample that contains values and I want to select a random number of values form that sample based on the all_indexes...

Comment: You're generating a list of 75287520 elements to shuffle - that's likely not to be quick... Do you definitely need to do this for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I need to have 20 dimensions for my problem, not 5, I thank the way that I doing is not the right one.

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely rethink your approach. Even without the shuffle, this will run you out of memory well before you hit 20 dimensions.

Comment: It is the list creation that is consuming  the whole time. Some generator ways might do faster.

Comment: @Austin I had the same thought and tested it. The shuffle is taking longer than the list creation by a large margin.

Comment: @Austin do you know some examples of generator ways might do faster?

Comment: From what @AndrewMcDowell observed, shuffling takes longer. `shuffle` takes a sequence as parameter and I'm not sure a generator is possible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you're generating a very large list and then shuffling it. This is not going to be quick but depending on what you actually need, there may be faster ways of getting what you want.

I ran your code on my machine and found that generating the list of all combinations took about 8 seconds and shuffling it took around 75. If you need to increase the dimension, this time will significantly increase, not to mention the memory requirements of storing very large arrays could start to become significant.

If you are not going to need all of the random indexes, you may be better off sampling each time using,

```
random.sample(range(sample_size), dimension)
```

This returns a random collection of distinct `dimension` elements from `0` to `sample_size`. This took about 0.0001 second to run with your values of `dimension` and `sample_size`. If you don't need too many of the random values, then you'll be much quicker (and memory efficient) generating a new one each time.

There are two issues with this that I can see. Firstly you aren't guaranteed that each new sample won't be a repeat of a previous one, but this can be easily resolved by storing them as you go, and checking if they've been used already.

```
new_sample = random.sample(range(sample_size), dimension)
if new_sample not in random_indexes:
    random_indexes.append(new_sample)
else:
    # Handle this however you need.
```

This does add more run time, but again will be faster if you don't need too many of your samples.

The other difference is that the approach you have used generates tuples of elements that are always sorted so (1,2,3,4,5) will be an element of `all_indexes`, but (5,4,3,2,1) will not. Using `random.sample` can produce them in any order, so both could occur. If this is an issue, then you will have to resolve this. Perhaps by putting them into a set before adding them to the list:

```
new_sample = set(random.sample(range(sample_size), dimension))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this a good comment, the problem know that Yes I need all the random numbers of the index that mean if my sample_size is 10 then I need 10 random of numbers of index [(0, 2), (0, 1),.......  if the dimension is 2

Comment: at the end, I use this `random_indexx = random.sample ( all_indexes, sample_size )` to select my random numbers of the index  that equivalent to the sample_size I did this way because I want to make sure i will not have any duplicates

Comment: That's good, you're definitely better off sampling then. If you only need `sample_size` samples, then you don't need all of `all_indexes`. With `dimension = 2` and `sample_size = 10` for example, the size of `all_indexes` would be 45. In your original example, `sample_size` is 100, but `all_indexes` is of size 75287520.